# Muenchian method for nested elements

Tags: xml, xslt, muenchian-grouping

my xml input is-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<foo>  <bar>bar</bar> 
       <bar>bar</bar> 
       <foobar><baz>baz</baz></foobar> 
       <foobar>foobar</foobar>
       <bar>bar</bar>
       <bar>bar</bar> 
</foo>
```

Output using xslt  should be

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <foo>  
 <s> 
 <s> 
 <bar>bar</bar>  
 <bar>bar</bar>
 </s>
 <s> 
 <foobar><baz>baz</baz></foobar>
 <foobar>foobar></foobar>
 </s> 
 <s>      
 <bar>bar</bar>  
 <bar>bar</bar> 
 </s>
 </s>
</foo>
```

the output should have sequence-of elements inside a parent. Mixed sequence-of elements will be moved inside parents node “s”. the xslt file that is used is-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="adjacentByName" match="*/*" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[not(name()=name(current()))][1])" />

<xsl:template match="/*">
<foo><s>
<xsl:for-each select="*[generate-id()=generate-id(key('adjacentByName', generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[not(name()=name(current()))][1]))[1])]">
    <s>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('adjacentByName', generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[not(name()=name(current()))][1]))">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </s>
</xsl:for-each>
</s></foo>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the problem is in output baz element (child element of first foobar element) is with both bar and foobar sequences.

```
<foo>
<s>
    <s>
        <bar>bar</bar>
        <bar>bar</bar>
        **<baz>baz</baz>**
    </s>
    <s>
        <foobar>
            <baz>baz</baz>
        </foobar>
        <foobar>foobar</foobar>
    </s>
    <s>
        <bar>bar</bar>
        <bar>bar</bar>
    </s>
</s>
</foo>
```

How can i remove baz element from bar sequences. Many thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can use `current()` in an XSL key. (Sure, you can, but it does not what you seem to think it does.) Also, an `<xsl:for-each select="condition">` that contains nothing but an `<xsl:copy-of select="." />` can be replaced by an `<xsl:copy-of select="condition" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="kGroupLeader" match="*" use="
    generate-id(self::*[name() != name(preceding-sibling::*[1])])
  " />

  <xsl:template match="foo">
    <xsl:copy>
      <s>
        <xsl:for-each select="*[key('kGroupLeader', generate-id())]">
          <s>
            <xsl:copy-of select=". | following-sibling::*[
              name() = name(current())
              and
              generate-id(current()) = generate-id(
                preceding-sibling::*[key('kGroupLeader', generate-id())][1]
              )
            ]" />
          </s>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </s>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With your input of

```
<foo>
  <bar id="1">bar</bar> 
  <bar id="2">bar</bar> 
  <foobar id="3"><baz>baz</baz></foobar> 
  <foobar id="4">foobar</foobar>
  <bar id="5">bar</bar>
  <bar id="6">bar</bar> 
</foo>
```

this produces

```
<foo>
  <s>
    <s>
      <bar id="1">bar</bar>
      <bar id="2">bar</bar>
    </s>
    <s>
      <foobar id="3">
        <baz>baz</baz>
      </foobar>
      <foobar id="4">foobar</foobar>
    </s>
    <s>
      <bar id="5">bar</bar>
      <bar id="6">bar</bar>
    </s>
  </s>
</foo>
```

Comment: @Tomalak..i have another question.if i want to use this method only for more than one same element(if all the elements are different like 1 foobar and 1 bar element then dont do this) where do i use the counter..

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *"this"*, but if you think about it for a bit then there's a pretty easy answer to your question. You just have to change the template's behavior depending on whether there's a element with the same name following a group leader. You'll figure it out.

Comment: thnx..i meant "this" by the whole process..if all elements are different then input and output would be same..thnx..